# Laravel Policy and Show Method with View Method logical Problem

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Policys and want to be sure that I am prevent data to be shown of other users.
In every Table I have the column 'user_id' and check if the current logged in user with his id the same with the data and his user_id.
In this specific case I have a table of Objects and Objektverwaltung where the objekt_id is given as foreign key.

I want to use my policy to be sure that just the data for the given object was shown in objektverwaltung where the foreign key 'objekt_id' is given.

ObjektVerwaltung Controller with the show method:

```
public function show($objektvwId) {

        $objektId = ObjektVerwaltung::with('Objekt')->find($objektvwId);

        
        
        $this->authorize('view', $objektId);
        $objekte = ObjektVerwaltung::where('objekt_id',$objektvwId)->get();
  
        
        
     
        return view('objekte.verwaltung', compact('objekte'));
    }
```

Policy:

```
  public function view(User $user, ObjektVerwaltung $objektVerwaltung)
    {
        
        return $objektVerwaltung->user_id === $user->id;
    }
```

Models:

```
class ObjektVerwaltung extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'objekte_verwaltungens';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id','objekt_id','key', 'value'];

    public function Objekt() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Objekt::class);
    }
}

class Objekt extends Model
{

    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'objekts';

    protected $fillable = ['name','strasse', 'hausnummer', 'plz', 'ort', 'user_id'];


    public function Mieter() {
        return $this->hasMany(Mieter::class);
    }

    public function Company() {
        return $this->belongTo(Company::class);
    }

    public function Objektverwaltung() {
        return $this->hasMany(ObjektVerwaltung::class);
    }


}
```

I learned that I can easily use find() as method for the Models to validate data. But in this specific case I have to check for the objekt_id (foreign key in objektverwaltung) and not for the ID and because of that I cant use find(). But if I use where or another method I cant use my policy and always getting unauthorized.

I tried to use the with method on the model but maybe there is a better way to my problem. I strongly believe.

Thanks!

This could be solution, but I am getting always "Unauthorized" and do not get to the policy: `$objekt= ObjektVerwaltung::where('objekt_id', $objektId)->get();        $this->authorize('view', $objekt);`

Comment: can you please add the model class ?

Comment: Added in my text

Comment: Your controller is confusing. This `$objektId = ObjektVerwaltung::with('Objekt')->find($objektvwId);` returns `$objektVerwaltung` and yet the variable is named `$objektId ` .

Same for `$objekte = ObjektVerwaltung::where('objekt_id',$objektvwId)->get();`. You are using `objekt_id` to fetch `ObjektVerwaltung` and it will return nothing.

Please look into these issues first. I believe your policy has been correctly implemented. Data is just not being fetched properly from the DB.

Comment: Hi, the variable $objektvwId is the ID of the column objekt_id in ObjektVerwaltung. I dont want find() the id in ObjektVerwaltung. I want to find the objekt_id in ObjektVerwaltung. And I try to find a solution how I can fix it here with the policy. It is important to check if the objekt_id and f.e. user_id is correct for the data

Comment: This could be solution, but I am getting always "Unauthorized" and do not get to the policy:    `$objekt= ObjektVerwaltung::where('objekt_id', $objektId)->get();
         $this->authorize('view', $objekt);`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I had to use my ObjektPolicy, because I am using the objekt_id Key.